# MySQL CONCAT returns NULL if any field contain NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, concatenation

I have following data in my table "devices"

```
affiliate_name  affiliate_location  model     ip             os_type    os_version 

cs1             inter               Dell     10.125.103.25   Linux      Fedora  
cs2             inter               Dell     10.125.103.26   Linux      Fedora  
cs3             inter               Dell     10.125.103.27   NULL       NULL    
cs4             inter               Dell     10.125.103.28   NULL       NULL
```

I executed below query

```
SELECT CONCAT(`affiliate_name`,'-',`model`,'-',`ip`,'-',`os_type`,'-',`os_version`) AS device_name
FROM devices
```

It returns result given below

```
cs1-Dell-10.125.103.25-Linux-Fedora
cs2-Dell-10.125.103.26-Linux-Fedora
(NULL)
(NULL)
```

How to come out of this so that it should ignore NULL AND result should be

```
cs1-Dell-10.125.103.25-Linux-Fedora
cs2-Dell-10.125.103.26-Linux-Fedora
cs3-Dell-10.125.103.27-
cs4-Dell-10.125.103.28-
```

Comment: Just ran into this as well. I would consider near to insane that this is the default action. The exact opposite of programming with the least amount of surprises.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

convert the `NULL` values with empty string by wrapping it in `COALESCE`

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(`affiliate_name`,''),'-',COALESCE(`model`,''),'-',COALESCE(`ip`,''),'-',COALESCE(`os_type`,''),'-',COALESCE(`os_version`,'')) AS device_name
FROM devices
```

Comment: You can use if  select CONCAT(if(affiliate_name is null ,'',affiliate_name),'- ',if(model is null ,'',affiliate_name)) as model from devices

Comment: For those wonder, as I did, what the `COALESCE` function does: it returns the first non-`NULL` value parameter passed to it (or `NULL` if all parameters are `NULL`). By passing an empty string as the second parameter, you are guaranteeing it will not return `NULL`.

Comment: mysql has IFNULL(arg, default) instead COALESCE with the same syntax

Comment: not work for me , still return null value when join column A = 'data person' with column B = null value . anyone know why ?

Comment: ah we cant use COALESCE(`column`, null) , i copied your code, and now its work . but for mysql 8 , we just use `COALESCE(column, '')` if we use `'`'` parenthesis , its return unknow column, and if we use null after define column, its return null if some value is null.

Comment: we cant added separator between `COALESCE` its still return null value

Comment: when use `COALESCE` every on `CONCAT` must be use `COALESCE` , if not do that still return on null value.

Answer (score 169):

Use [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead:

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',`affiliate_name`,`model`,`ip`,`os_type`,`os_version`) AS device_name FROM devices
```

Comment: Sorry neeraj i missed the '_' between Concat and WS Please try again with CONCAT_WS().I have updated the answer please check,

Comment: Note that this solution hides a complete "column" (including the separator) if one of the middle fields is NULL. So this answer is only correct assuming that only the last field(s) can be NULL. Depending on your need, the COALEASE() answer below might be better.

Comment: This only works if you want every member separated by the same separator. CONCAT doesn't have this limitation. I posted the solution as an answer here

Comment: Dangerous: `SELECT CONCAT_WS(';',1,NULL)` is identical with `SELECT  CONCAT_WS(';',NULL,1)`. Both gives `1`. This is a problem if you want `1;` respectively `;1`.

Answer (score 19):

`CONCAT_WS` still produces null for me if the first field is Null. I solved this by adding a zero length string at the beginning as in

```
CONCAT_WS("",`affiliate_name`,'-',`model`,'-',`ip`,'-',`os_type`,'-',`os_version`)
```

however

```
CONCAT("",`affiliate_name`,'-',`model`,'-',`ip`,'-',`os_type`,'-',`os_version`)
```

produces Null when the first field is Null.

Comment: obviously, because the first field is the string that it will concatenate with (WS = with string)

Comment: CONCAT_WS is short for Concatenate With Separator. The first parameter is the separator and cannot be null. This is probably what you want instead: `CONCAT_WS("-", affiliate_name, model, ip, os_type, os_version)`

Answer (score 15):

To have the same flexibility in CONCAT_WS as in CONCAT (if you don't want the same separator between every member for instance) use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("",affiliate_name,':',model,'-',ip,... etc)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT CONCAT(isnull(`affiliate_name`,''),'-',isnull(`model`,''),'-',isnull(`ip`,''),'-',isnull(`os_type`,''),'-',isnull(`os_version`,'')) AS device_name
FROM devices
```

Comment: in mysql IFNULL()  instead of ISNULL()

Answer (score 12):

**Reason:**

> [MySQL :: Reference Manual :: 12.8 String Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) says:
>
> `CONCAT()` returns **NULL** if any argument is **NULL**.

**Solution:**

> [MySQL :: Reference Manual :: 12.5 Flow Control Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) says:
>
> ```sql
> IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
> ```
>
> If *expr1* is not **NULL**, **IFNULL()** returns *expr1*; otherwise it returns expr2.

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        IFNULL(`affiliate_name`, ''),
        '-',
        IFNULL(`model`, ''),
        '-',
        IFNULL(`ip`, ''),
        '-',
        IFNULL(`os_type`, ''),
        '-',
        IFNULL(`os_version`, '')
    ) AS device_name
FROM
    devices
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use if statement like below

```
select CONCAT(if(affiliate_name is null ,'',affiliate_name),'- ',if(model is null ,'',affiliate_name)) as model from devices
```