# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I did a trigger validating two columns,when only one of them is wrong it show the message normally,when both are wrong I get the error

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: ''

I believe it's on the Concat part am I missing something on the function?

```
 if(RESULTADO = false) then
    set msg = "Cpf invalido";
 end if;

    if(new.idadeproprietario <18) then

        set msg2 = "Idade invalida";
    end if;

    if (msg is not null) or (msg2 is not null) then 

            select Concat(msg, msg2) into msg3;

        Signal sqlstate '40000' set message_text = msg3;
    end if;
```

Comment: concat will return Null when either value is null, you may need to coalesce msg and msg2 into empty sets like `select Concat(coalesce(msg,'',coalesce(msg2,''')) into msg3;  another stack article on topic... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741314/mysql-concat-returns-null-if-any-field-contain-null

Comment: @xQbert it worked just had to change a few things,for future reference  select Concat(coalesce(msg,''),coalesce(msg2,'')) into msg3;

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
select Concat(msg,msg2) into msg3;
```

to

```
select Concat(msg,msg2) as msg3;
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '<Some Value>'
```

I was getting this warning as an error while creating a table using `CTAS` also while inserting data into an already created table.

This was happening due to using `count()` on the column values. Use `Sum()` method instead of `count()`

Usually, `Select` statement gives output without error but it gives `Warning`(Which can be checked by enabling warning `\W`). This gives error while `INSERT/CTAS`.