# How to concate two columns as one with a space betwen them while using CDbCommands in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

The query I have written is:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

where

```
$sql= 'SELECT `EMAIL` as `EMAIL_ADDRESS`, concat(`FIRST_NAME`, `' '` ,`LAST_NAME`) as `FULL_NAME`, `PHONE_NUMBER` FROM `claim_request`';
```

What I want to do is FULL_NAME = Mark Taylor. But CDbcommand is not adding space it gives the output as FULL_NAME = MarkTaylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

`$sql= 'SELECTE MAIL as EMAIL_ADDRESS, concat(FIRST_NAME," ",LAST_NAME) as FULL_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER FROM claim_request';`

Instead of single quotation mark, you can use double quotation mark...

Answer (score 2):

As a side note `CONCAT` will do what you want but it has some limitation as it will give correct result only when both `FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME` exist in database if any one is `NULL` then it will give null in result so i suggest to use `CONCAR_WS` for this if you think that `LAST_NAME` may be empty for some users

```
$sql= 'SELECTE MAIL as EMAIL_ADDRESS, CONCAT_WS(" ",FIRST_NAME,,LAST_NAME) as FULL_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER FROM claim_request';
```

for more info please read http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

Also see this question for more info [MySQL CONCAT returns NULL if any field contain NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741314/mysql-concat-returns-null-if-any-field-contain-null)