# SQL query to find values without NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have doubt on my SQL.

Please find the query

```
select a.id, a.phone, b.list,c.ctitle,l,
       if(last_id!=0 and date(activity)=date(start_date), 
       CONCAT(ag.firstname,' ‘,ag.lastname) ,’')
from table name a 
left join <all other tables>
where a.cid = '100' and a.date between '2013-05-01' and '2015-06-14';
```

The output is showing properly.currently i am getting firstname and lastname. But for some entries first name and last name empty. I need to modify the query so that i can print the non-null value of the column **if(last_id!=0 and date(activity)=date(start_date), CONCAT(ag.firstname,' ‘,ag.lastname) ,’')** ie same query excluding the null entries for firstname and last name. I tried IS NOT NULL but not working.

Please help

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Add to the where clause `AND ag.firstname IS NOT NULL AND ag.lastname IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you have a problem with `NULL`s.  One simple solution is to use `concat_ws()`:

```
   concat_ws(' ', ag.firstname, ag.lastname)
```

If either name is `NULL`, then it is just ignored in the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find the answer here :[MySQL CONCAT returns NULL if any field contain NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741314/mysql-concat-returns-null-if-any-field-contain-null)

also you can use IFNull syntax for this:

> `CONCAT(IFNull(ag.firstname,''),IFNull(ag.lastname,''))`