# CONCAT return null

Tags: mysql, null, string-function

I am trying to get three columns as a string but for some reason I only get NULL.

this is the code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', city, ' ', country) FROM places
```

the table places contains the three columns name, city and country and it is not empty, however, it can contain NULL in some of the columns.

The result:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL,
etc
```

I tried the answer from this post [MySQL CONCAT returns NULL if any field contain NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741314/mysql-concat-returns-null-if-any-field-contain-null) and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: and what is in result when `SELECT name, city, country, CONCAT(name, ' ', city, ' ', country) FROM places` ?

Comment: It shows all the columns and the column with the concant still all null

Comment: I disagree with the duplicated question, the answer in this post is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name, city, country) FROM places
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. Good answer!

Comment: this is the response

Comment: It's not just MySQL 8.0. This function has existed in MySQL for years. If only people would read the documentation... For example, here's the link to the MySQL 5.5 doc on this function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: It is definitively the first time I see a function like this one

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for pointing out, I have rolledback my edit

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like `COALESCE(name, '')` to convert a null string to an empty string. Since null means unknown, mysql will not assume it means empty string. Unknown concatenated with anything is still unknown. You have to tell it explicitly to treat it as empty string and that is what the coalesce is for.

Comment: it shows a weird result, with only some partial columns, not all the info that it should show.