# Multiple concat with like not showing the output in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation, sql-like

I am using multiple concat with like but I am not getting all the output from the table. I am using below SQL query below in the database.

```
  select 
  company_id as ID, 
  concat(
    c.list_rank, '|||', c.company_name, 
    '|||', c.company_size, '|||', c.industry
  ) as post_content, 
  c.admin_approved from company22 c where company_name like ' % XYZ % ';
```

I am getting below output. Post content is showing null but I have all the data in the table

[image]

Comment: You should use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values by a space or an empty string. See [MySQL CONCAT returns NULL if any field contain NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741314/mysql-concat-returns-null-if-any-field-contain-null)

Comment: @SalmanA, I have shared the output of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of the values you're concatenating must be `NULL`. Since any operation involving NULL returns NULL, that makes the final result `NULL`.

Use `IFNULL()` to replace the null values with an empty string.

```
CONCAT_WS('|||', IFNULL(c.list_rank, ''), IFNULL(c.company_name, ''), IFNULL(c.company_size, ''), IFNULL(c.industry, '')) AS post_content
```

I also use `CONCAT_WS()` to simplify joining several values with the same delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It's working

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **CONCAT_WS**

like

```
 concat_ws('',
    c.list_rank, '|||', c.company_name, 
    '|||', c.company_size, '|||', c.industry
  ) as post_content
```

The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the arguments. If the separator is NULL , the result is NULL ; all other NULL values are skipped. This makes CONCAT_WS() suitable when you want to concatenate some values and avoid losing all information if one of them is NULL.

Comment: You didn't fill in the first argument, shouldn't it be `'|||'`?

Comment: How will this solve the problem of the result being `NULL`?

Comment: @Barmar - The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the arguments. If the separator is NULL , the result is NULL ; all other NULL values are skipped. This makes CONCAT_WS() suitable when you want to concatenate some values and avoid losing all information if one of them is NULL .

see: https://www.google.com/search?q=translate&rlz=1C5CHFA_enDE934DE936&oq=trans&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59j69i65j69i60l2j69i65l2.2314j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You should explain that in the answer.